# Given an example of a function in real number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f$ is continuous at $0$ but discontinuous in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: Let $g$ such that $g(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $g(x)=0$ otherwise. Take $f(x)=xg(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take
$$
f(x)=xI_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)
$$
where $I$ is the indicator function.

Answer (score 0):

To get a function which is continuous at $0$ and discontinuous on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ the other answers are good.

But we can also go further. For $2\leq k\in\mathbb N$, the function 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^k & x\in\mathbb Q\\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$
it $(k-1)$-times continuously differentiable at $0$ while discontinuous on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

In addition, we can consider the function 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
exp\left(-\frac1{x^2}\right) & x\in\mathbb Q\\ 0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$
which is infinitely differentiable at $0$ while discontinuous on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.